# Retrieve hashed password in Odoo 13 using API

Tags: python, api, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-13

In Odoo 11 I could retrieve the hashed password from *password_crypt* field in *res_users* table, but this doesn't work in **Odoo 13** any more.

I used the Odoo 11 credentials to login to other applications, which can't be integrated in Odoo. This authentication stopped working as the password seems to be write only. Now I'm looking for a way to get read access to the Odoo password, any clue how to do that using the API?

I use the following python test code, but password field is empty:

```
import xmlrpclib

common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

user = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.users', 'search_read',
    [[['id', '=', 2]]],
    {})[0]

print user
```

Any idea how to **read** the write only hashed password?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `read()` method is overridden on `res.users` to exclude some fields, such as the password field, I would (not*) recommend to create a method on the `res.users` that does a SQL read like so:

```
def read_password(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    self.env.cr.execute("SELECT password FROM res_users WHERE id=%s", self.id)
```

*Disclaimer: There is a reason that Odoo hides the password field, so here you are essentially bypassing Odoo's security. You will need to make triple sure that this method is 100% secure. Some ideas:

- Add a check for the correct API key
- Only allow a certain user to execute this method
- Only allow a certain IP source to execute this method